# add an op tensorflow debugging

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I would like to know how you can print out the values of the input tensor when adding a new op to tensorflow for debugging purposes. I have been following the tutorial with cuda_op_kernel.cc as follows:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace tensorflow;  // NOLINT(build/namespaces)

REGISTER_OP("AddOne")
    .Input("input: int32")
    .Output("output: int32")
    .Doc(R"doc(
Adds 1 to all elements of the tensor.

output: A Tensor.
  output = input + 1
)doc");

void AddOneKernelLauncher(const int* in, const int N, int* out);

class AddOneOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit AddOneOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Grab the input tensor
    const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
    auto input = input_tensor.flat<int32>();

    // Create an output tensor
    Tensor* output_tensor = nullptr;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, input_tensor.shape(),
                                                     &output_tensor));
    auto output = output_tensor->template flat<int32>();

    // Set all but the first element of the output tensor to 0.
    const int N = input.size();
    // Call the cuda kernel launcher
    std::cout << input.data() << std::endl;
    std::cout << input.data()[0] << std::endl;
    AddOneKernelLauncher(input.data(), N, output.data());
  }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("AddOne").Device(DEVICE_GPU), AddOneOp);
```

The second std::cout causes a segfault. My understanding is input.data() should be a const int array, so I can print out its values. What's wrong?

Comment: Note that there exists a [`tf.Print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) operation, mostly for debugging purposes, that you can apply to the inputs of your operation before passing them in.

Comment: As for the error, could it be that the tensor is actually empty? In any case, the implementation of the printing operation ([see here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.10.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc#L54)) is based on [`tensorflow::Tensor.SummarizeValue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#summarizevalue) so you could look into that...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why. Input.data() is a pointer onto address in the GPU. The stream executor has evidently already put it there. Attempting to dereference on CPU is bad.